# How to get the index of the selected text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I haven't found any plugins which meet all criteria:
I want a highlighter. I want to be able to highlight text, store the text in order of selection, and I want to automatically select all the word if they choose just part of a word.

this is what I have so far:

JS:

```
function getSelectionHtml() {
    var html = "";
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            var container = document.createElement("div");
            for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
                container.appendChild(sel.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
            }
            html = container.innerHTML;
        }
    } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined") {
        if (document.selection.type == "Text") {
            html = document.selection.createRange().htmlText;
        }
    }

    return html;
}

function highlightAndStore() {

    var html = getSelectionHtml().toString();
    if(html.indexOf('<span class="highlighted">') === 0) {
        html = html.replace('<span class="highlighted">','');
       // alert(html);
    }
    var newHtml = html;
    var prepend = '<span class="highlighted">';
    var postpend = '</span>';
    var allhtml = $('#highlightable').html().toString();

    var hightlightableHtml = $('#highlightable').html().toString();
    var indexofHighlight = hightlightableHtml.indexOf(html);
alert(indexofHighlight +'          '+hightlightableHtml);
        /*
    if (indexofHighlight < 0) {
        var temp = '<span class="highlighted">' + html;
        var indexofHighlight = hightlightableHtml.indexOf(html);
    }*/
    var shortenedHtml = hightlightableHtml.substring(0, indexofHighlight);

    var spanStarts = locations('<span class="highlighted">', shortenedHtml);
    var spanEnds = locations('</span>', shortenedHtml);
   // alert(shortenedHtml + '                              ' + spanStarts.length + '   ' + spanEnds.length + '     '+indexofHighlight);
    if (spanStarts.length > spanEnds.length) // span inside or after selection
    {
        prepend = '';

        var insSS = locations('<span class="highlighted">', html);
        var insSE = locations('</span>', html);
        //alert('no. span starts: ' + insSS.length + '  ends: ' + insSE.length);
        if (insSS.length > insSE.length) {
            postpend = postpend + '<span class="highlighted">';
        } else if (insSS.length == insSE.length) {
            postpend = '';
        }
    }
    newHtml = html.replace(/<span class="highlighted">/g, "");
    newHtml = newHtml.replace(/<\/span>/g, '');
    newHtml = prepend + newHtml + postpend;
    allhtml = allhtml.replace(html, newHtml);
    $('#highlightable').html(allhtml);
}

function locations(substring, string) {
    var a = [],
        i = -1;
    while ((i = string.indexOf(substring, i + 1)) >= 0) a.push(i);
    return a;
}
$(function () {

    $('#highlightable').mouseup(highlightAndStore);

});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="highlightable">
    <p id="p1">stibulum nisl orci, viverra in sollicitudin sed, iaculis vel erat. Nam lacus quam, volutpat et porta non, consequat ac tortor. Fusce non lorem vitae</p>
    <p>libero imperdiet convallis. Morbi vestibulum viverra ligula, porttitor dapibus justo dictum ut. Pellentesque eget laoreet metus. Curabitur rhoncus consectetur nulla, id imperdiet nulla pellentesque sit amet. Cras sodales arcu ac orci suscipit pulvinar sollicitudin risus gravida. Praesent condimentum erat sit amet ipsum tristique mattis. Cras dolor ante, hendrerit vel suscipit a, pellentesque sit amet felis. Vivamus suscipit, tellus ut sollicitudin pulvinar, odio urna auctor quam, ut bibendum ipsum arcu ac nibh. Phasellus sollicitudin, ipsum at pretium consectetur, arcu nisi auctor quam, a lobortis erat neque viverra diam. Nam congue libero sed est gravida dignissim. Nulla pulvinar condimentum diam in porta. Aenean id interdum odio. Fusce cursus sagittis urna dictum scelerisque. Sed nunc massa, cursus et pharetra at, ullamcorper vel est. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut accumsan commodo lorem, gravida rutrum diam venenatis eu.</p>
    <p id="p2">stibulum nisl orci, viverra in sollicitudin sed, iaculis vel erat. Nam lacus quam, volutpat et porta non, consequat ac tortor. Fusce non lorem vitae libero imperdiet convallis. Morbi vestibulum viverra ligula, porttitor dapibus justo dictum ut. Pellentesque eget laoreet metus. Curabitur rhoncus consectetur nulla, id imperdiet nulla pellentesque sit amet. Cras sodales arcu ac orci suscipit pulvinar sollicitudin risus gravida. Praesent condimentum erat sit amet ipsum tristique mattis. Cras dolor ante, hendrerit vel suscipit a, pellentesque sit amet felis. Vivamus suscipit, tellus ut sollicitudin pulvinar, odio urna auctor quam, ut bibendum ipsum arcu ac nibh. Phasellus sollicitudin, ipsum at pretium consectetur, arcu nisi auctor quam, a lobortis erat neque viverra diam. Nam congue libero sed est gravida dignissim. Nulla pulvinar condimentum diam in porta. Aenean id interdum odio. Fusce cursus sagittis urna dictum scelerisque. Sed nunc massa, cursus et pharetra at, ullamcorper vel est. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut accumsan commodo lorem, gravida rutrum diam venenatis eu.</p>
</div>
```

1. code explanation

On mouse up, the selected text is grabbed in HTML form. Then it gets all the html inside the highlightable area, and finds the first instance of this html match. The html of the entire highlightable area is then split into a substring "shortenedHtml" which is the HTML of the area PRIOR to the user selection. It then counts the spans. It works out, if the number of start and end spans are equal, then just check the selection area counts. If there are more span starts however, this selection starts within another currently highlighted area, so dont add a span start tag, just an end.

It also checks inside the selected html for the same idea, making sure span tags arent going to break. This bit works perfectly from what I can tell - any excess span tags within the selection are removed for a clean output.

1. code issues:

Ok, so far I have a highlight working, but it's very buggy. If you keep the alerts in it becomes apparent the reason it doesn't work is that the index is getting confused. Basically if you select just a single character half way down, it just thinks you selected the first instance of that character... Is there a way to get the instance of the index within the range function? If not, any better ways? I am thinking for selecting the whole word I can just do a search back until the first space, but I can't even start that until these indexes are working!

I am thinking if there's a way to add a temp span around the selection within the getSelectionHtml function I can search for " and then just remove this.

Please note - I dont need functionality such as nested tables etc highlightable.

Many thanks

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle for this?

Comment: No one will read that many line of code. post only codes that are relevant to your question.

Comment: Sure, here! :) http://jsfiddle.net/TTr8E/

Comment: Could you give a bit more detail about exactly what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @user2330270 Still this is a lot of code to be read... You won't get many answers if you have this large code... Reduce it to a part where you have any problem...

Comment: @j809 That's why I explained what I need and which point it should be placed...

Comment: @TimDown I think the best thing that could happen would be in the function getSelectionHtml() before returning the html string of what has been selected, it wraps the selection with a <span class="temp"></span> , but I don't know how to do this

Comment: My question was about the functionality you're trying to achieve, from the point of view of the user, rather than the technical details of achieving it.

Comment: the user needs to just highlight, but behind the scenes I need to store what they have selected. Furthermore, when they highlight part of a word, it automatically will select the whole word.